# Adding javascript to a hyperlink control

Tags: javascript, c#

Trying to add a Javascript on a hyperlink click event.
Here, I get the Name of the hyper link, but nothing happens when i try to click on the hyperlink.

```
tblCell = new HtmlTableCell();
List<string> liEmailIdsForCC = new List<string>();
if(some condition)
{
liEmailIdsForCC .add("someitem");
}

HyperLink hpOwnerName = new HyperLink();
hpOwnerName.Text += string.Format("({0})  ", "FullName");
string args = string.Format("{0},{1}"
                           , this
                           , liEmailIdsForCC                           
                           );

var onClick = String.Format("javascript:OnNameClick({0});return false;", args);
hpOwnerName.Attributes.Add("onclick", onClick);
tblCell.Controls.Add(hpOwnerName);
```

Now, in this javascript, I am just trying to alert the first item in the list

```
function OnNameClick(sender, list) {
    alert(li[0]);
}
```

Comment: But li[0] where is it? It does not sending like a parameters.

Comment: Why are you sending a comma delimited string as an argument?  You are also converting `this` to a string, which will not be what you want.  And as @WilfredoP states, in your javascript function `li` doesnt exist.  I think you mean `list`

Comment: Yes, list[0]. But nothing happens on clicking the hyperlink

Comment: Do you see your JavaScript code in page source in your browser?

Comment: @zmechanic Yes, I can

Answer (score 1):

The client-side script won't have access to the server-side List. I don't know offhand what liEmailIdsForCC.ToString will return, but I don't think it's not going to be something JavaScript can use. If you want to have access to the string list, I'd convert it to a JavaScript array. Something like the following. Though you should probably escape the strings.

```
tblCell = new HtmlTableCell();
List<string> liEmailIdsForCC = new List<string>();
if(some condition)
{
    liEmailIdsForCC.add("someitem");
}

HyperLink hpOwnerName = new HyperLink();
hpOwnerName.Text += string.Format("(FullName)  ", "FullName");

string listJSArray = string.Format("['{0}']", string.Join("', '", liEmailIdsForCC.ToArray());

var onClick = string.Format("OnNameClick(this, {0}); return false;", listJSArray);
hpOwnerName.Attributes.Add("onclick", onClick);
tblCell.Controls.Add(hpOwnerName);

// javascript code...
function OnNameClick(source, list) {
    alert(list[0]);
}
```

Comment: I need to pass'this;, as I have few more parameters contained

Comment: this, as you're using it, refers to the class, not the object that's causing it to be called. I've modified it to pass the html element that called it, which is what I think "source" usually is in ASP.NET.